# An easy way to find the PDF of $XY/Z$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that we know the joint distribution $f_{X,Y,Z}$. I want to find the PDF of $W = XY/Z$ in a way that does not involve too much calculation.

I have thought about first finding the Marginalized PDF $f_{X,Y}$, since we have $XY$ in the numerator. Then I have heard that there was a way to, for example, substitute a random variable $M$, so that we can get to the Joint PDF of $f_{XY, M}$, and after that find $f_{XY, Z}$. Then we introduce another random variable $N$, find  $f_{XY/Z, N}$ and finally marginalize out to get our desired distribution $f_{XY/Z}$.

I have all these hints, but I still have no idea how to perform this. In particular, the introduction of random variables $M$ and $N$ confuse me. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are the variables independent?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Otherwise the problem would be too simple, wouldn't it? We would not need to introduce variables M or N.

Comment: Yeah it would be pretty simple if they are independent.